# Control dji mavic enterprise via virtual sticks

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am trying to control drone with command `sendVirtualStickFlightControlData`.
To move the drone left I use following  code.

```
    sendVirtualStickDataTask = new SendVirtualStickDataTask(0, -5, 0, 0);
    sendVirtualStickDataTimer = new Timer();
    sendVirtualStickDataTimer.schedule(sendVirtualStickDataTask, 100, 200);

    private class SendVirtualStickDataTask extends TimerTask {

    private float pitch;
    private float roll;
    private float yaw;
    private float throttle;
    private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public SendVirtualStickDataTask(float inputPitch, float inputRoll, float inputYaw, float inputThrottle) {
        pitch = inputPitch;
        roll = inputRoll;
        yaw = inputYaw;
        throttle = inputThrottle;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 300) {
            mFlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(new FlightControlData(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                                                new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final DJIError djiError) {

                }
            });
            cancel();
        } else {
            mFlightController
                    .sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(new FlightControlData(pitch,
                                                                             roll,
                                                                             yaw,
                                                                             throttle),
                                                       new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final DJIError djiError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    }
```

However, the drone moves to the left and then drops down sharply.

What is the reason for this drone behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue why it is dropping sharply downwards, since you are not changing the throttle values. Make sure to enable virtual sticks before usage. It might have to do with you needing to set maximum values. This code works fine for me.

```
    /* controllers virtual sticks command and triggers drone movement */
    private void sendVirtualStickCommands(final float pX, final float pY, final float pZ, final float pYaw){

        //maximum amounts
        float verticalJoyControlMaxSpeed = 2;
        float yawJoyControlMaxSpeed = 30;
        float pitchJoyControlMaxSpeed = 10;
        float rollJoyControlMaxSpeed = 10;

        //set yaw, pitch, throttle, roll
        float mYaw = (float)(yawJoyControlMaxSpeed * pYaw);
        float mThrottle = (float)(verticalJoyControlMaxSpeed * pZ);
        float mPitch = (float)(pitchJoyControlMaxSpeed * pX);
        float mRoll = (float)(rollJoyControlMaxSpeed * pY);

        if (mFlightController != null){
            //if virtual sticks are enabled, send the command, otherwise turn them on
            if (virtualSticksEnabled){
                mFlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(
                        new FlightControlData(
                                mPitch, mRoll, mYaw, mThrottle
                        ), new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                                if (djiError!=null){
                                    setResultToToast(djiError.getDescription());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            } else {
                setResultToToast("flight controller virtual mode off");
                //if not enabled, enable
                mFlightController.setVirtualStickModeEnabled(true, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                        if (djiError != null){
                            setResultToToast(djiError.getDescription());
                        }else
                        {
                            setResultToToast("Enable Virtual Stick Success");
                            virtualSticksEnabled = true;
                            sendVirtualStickCommands(pX, pY, pZ, pYaw);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } else{
            setResultToToast("Flight Controller Null");
        }

    }
```

Then, to move in a direction:

```
sendVirtualStickCommands(0.1f, 0, 0, 0);//move right
sendVirtualStickCommands(-0.1f, 0, 0, 0);//move left
sendVirtualStickCommands(0, 0.1f, 0, 0);//move forward
sendVirtualStickCommands(0, -0.1f, 0, 0);//move backwards
sendVirtualStickCommands(0, 0, 0.1f, 0);//move upwards
sendVirtualStickCommands(0, 0, -0.1f, 0);//move downwards
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
mFlightController.setRollPitchControlMode(RollPitchControlMode.VELOCITY);
mFlightController.setYawControlMode(YawControlMode.ANGULAR_VELOCITY);
mFlightController.setVerticalControlMode(VerticalControlMode.POSITION);
mFlightController.setRollPitchCoordinateSystem(FlightCoordinateSystem.BODY);
```

and set `mThrottle >= 0.0f`

in `VerticalControlMode.POSITION`, mThrottle is a flight height you want to set in meters above the ground. 
For example `mThrottle = 2.0f` means to move the drone to 2 meters above the ground. Set the height you want and the drone will rise to it or "drops down" if mThrottle = 0f.